# Getting upload and Download bandwidth in Android using NetworkCapabilities class

Tags: android, bandwidth

I am working on a small video streaming application.I want to get the upload and download speed of network in Android.i discovered that we can do that by using Android NetworkCapabilities class which provides functions

```
getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps()
Retrieves the downstream bandwidth for this network in Kbps. 
This always only refers to the estimated first hop transport bandwidth.

getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps ()
Retrieves the upstream bandwidth for this network in Kbps. 
This always only refers to the estimated first hop transport bandwidth.
```

1.What does **first hop** Here Mean ?

2.How to use them.Please provide some link for reference that how can we use them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that you're in an Activity you can get the info in this way:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network[] networks = cm.getAllNetworks();
...cycle or choose a network...
NetworkCapabilities capabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
```

The first hop means that it is an estimate of the capabilities of your link not an estimate of the bandwidth you'll get when your traffic will be routed over the network to reach your endpoint. Please note that this methods are availble from Lollipop.

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. Sir have u any idea that in Android how can i check download  and upload speed programatically. like  speedtest.net do.

Comment: I guess they use a Socket and a SocketServer to check how many bytes are sent and received during a fixed time period. The the speed is calculated ad bytes/time; it's not difficult to do, I believe there are many example available since the logic should be similar to what you would implement with a java app. By the way, you're implementing a streaming app and this kind of mechanisms should be handled by the protocol you're using. For example the RTCP protocol is something that can help you to understand how is the video quality going.

Comment: Sir actually the user can be in any part of the world,if we select a server which has Socketserver over it  in Australia and user is in UK then it will affect our performance. so i need to select a server which is nearby to the user location.

Comment: So basically, you're playing a video that you get from a server, and you have many server available all over the world? That was not clear in your question.

Comment: I would proceed in this way. Accept my answer if you believe that it's a good answer to your question, and post another question!